# BeautifulSoup type error

Tags: beautifulsoup

I don't understand this error. How do I get "content" to become writeable?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("http://www.asdf.fi/asdf.html"))

content = soup.find(id="content") 

with open("test.html", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(content)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot open a web page using `open()`. You'll need to use the `urllib` library (actually I use the `mechanize` library, it's easier to use).

Second, `open()` returns a `file` object, which cannot be passed to `BeautifulSoup()`. You'll need to write something like

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename).read())
```

`.read()` reads the whole file and returns the character buffer, which can be used to call `BeautifulSoup()`.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks.
BTW...
soup = BeautifulSoup(open( filename.read() ))

Comment: Nope, `.read()` is not a method of `str` class, it's a method of `file` class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some searching...

```
with open("test.html", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(content.encode('utf-8'))
```